# Too many instance variables to save/restore on Activity

Tags: android, design-patterns

I have many fields which should be saved/restored in Activity.

```
private int mPrevRdbDayId;
private ScrollView mScrView;
private TextView mTxtTitleFirst;
private TextView mTxtTitleSecond;
private TextView mTxtTitleCoin;
private ImageView mImgBackground;
private View mLoutColor;
private TextView mTxtTime;
private RadioGroup mRdgDay;
private RadioButton mRdbOtherDay;
private RadioGroup mRdgPrivacy;
private View mLoutFriends;
private EditText mEdtAddTxt;
private TextView mTxtAddMedia;
private TextView mTxtAddMap;
private SeekBar mSkbTime;

private View mLoutMap;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private FeedItem mFeedItem;
private RecyclerView mRvMedia;
private TextView mTxtMapPlace;
private TextView mTxtMapAddress;
private RecyclerView mRvRecipients;
private RecipientRecyclerAdapter mRvRecipientsAdapter;
private RecyclerLoader mRvFriends;
private List<ImageItem> mListMedia;
private List<ImageItem> mListPrepareVideo;
```

So I am supposed to save everything like this:

```
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("mPrevRdbDayId", mPrevRdbDayId);
     ....... and same for each field
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
  }
```

And then the same for onRestoreInstanceState, which seems like too boilplate code in approach. Is there any appropriate pattern to handle this case? Thx in advance.

Comment: Few of those fields would appear to belong in instance state: `mPrevRdbDayId` and *maybe* `mFeedItem`. None of the widgets go in instance state. Nor would a `RecyclerView.Adapter`, lists of images, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare What about all those TextViews, Spinner position, ....

Comment: @AftabHussain: Widgets cannot go in instance state. The text for those `TextView` widgets would need to be filled in for the new activity, but that should be handled by something else that is part of the instance state (`mFeedItem`, perhaps). Some state of some of the widgets might need to be handled manually in instance state, wherever the widget does not handle it for you, and wherever you need that state to be retained.